# Allowed memory size php

Tags: php

I have a question about php memory size.

In my `php.ini` file, the maximum amount of memory a script may consume is 128MB (`memory_limit = 128M`).

But I got this error message: `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 157286400 bytes exhausted.` Which means that I'm consuming 1GB of memory !

And when I added the line: `ini_set('memory_limit','200M');` it worked. I don't understand how can that be possible!

[image: error message]

Comment: *Which means that i'm consuming 1GB of memory* - what does - 157286400 is 150MB.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The memory limit is there for a reason - not everyone has a powerful computer with lots of memory. Your page is likely to crash the browser, so you might want to think about a way to NOT use so much memory, perhaps with a lazy load, or to summarize your data

Comment: @Mikkel please can you explain more !

Comment: How many elephants can you get in a mini?

Comment: there isn't enough space for it in a Mini.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a simple math error.

Comment: It depends on the size of the elephant @Mikkel ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Because of math. 157286400 bytes is 157.2864 Mb, nowhere near a Gb and well within the allowed 200 Mb size you set.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the riddle is "4 elephants, 2 in the front, and 2 in the back."

My point though, is that it's clearly ridiculous to be putting elephants in a mini, as a mini, or any other car, is not designed to carry elephants.

The same applies to the browser - treat it like a vehicle that will perform nicely when you give it a light load, but will struggle or break when you overload it.

I have no idea what your page is doing, but there are always ways to reduce the load - is it too much data, too many images, too much HTML that is causing you to up the memory limit?

It is possible to increase the memory, but that's just bad practice - think about what you are doing, and how you can make the page more efficient. If it's a list of 5,000 database items, for example, you could paginate the data, only displaying 50 per page. If each item shows an avatar, or some kind of image, the memory usage goes up quickly.

It's just common sense really, making pages that will load quickly, and work effortlessly

Comment: I'm parsing a about 500.000 lines of data (json docs), for now i treat them all each time i run the code, my question to you @mikkel  is, in your opinion  what's the optimal using of memory on a server ? And i have another last question : the size of all theese data is about 30Mo, why do we need 200Mo to treat it ? PS : i'm a begginer in data science so  please help me out ! thank you :)

Comment: Data (especially large data) should be stored in a database, either SQL or a document store. Reading in a large file and parsing it every time is inefficient, you can make the database engine do the heavy lifting, and ask it to fetch what you need, or do an aggregation on it, and give you a summary. A document store keeps the data in a structured format, so you don't have the overhead of parsing it every time you want to access it

Comment: Do you have some tutorials how to do that ?

Comment: It sounds like you need to do some learning about database technology. You can look on udemy for a video course, or you may be able to find a free lecture somewhere on the subject. Here is one, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yQ9TGFpDuM but you should do your own googling to find something suitable for you